# Passing an array as a query string parameter for an API

Tags: php, api, query-string

I have some API instructions I am trying to follow

(string) source
(string) key
(string) params[file]
(string) params[gender] 
(int) params[age]

I get how to make the API calls but where it has an array for params (file, gender and age) how to I put that into a query string?

The call works with something like this:

GET https://api-url.com/api?source=lorem&key=dolor

But how would I append that with the params? params[file]=file_name.gif ??

That doesn't seem to work but I'm open to the fact something else could be wrong - just wanted to check how you pass an array in a query string?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's `params[file]=xy` in the query string:

```
your-url/api?source=lorem&key=dolor&params[file]=file_name.gif&params[age]=23..
```

Access in PHP: `$yourfile = $_GET['params']['file'];`